# back reference with sed command getting unexpected result

Tags: unix, sed, backreference

File Content

```
abab102
cdcd103
efef105
```

I want the username and id separated. Here, abab is user and 102 is id.

I use the command

```
sed 's/\([a-z]\)\{4\}\([0-9]\)\{3\}/Username:\1 ID:\2/' file.txt
```

Get this

```
Username:b ID:2
Username:d ID:3
Username:f ID:5
```

But I am expecting

```
Username:abab ID:102
Username:cdcd ID:103
Username:efef ID:105
```

But using the command

```
sed -e 's/\([a-z]\)\{4\}/Username:&/' -e 's/\([0-9]\)\{3\}/ID:&/' file2.txt
```

Output

```
Username:ababID:102
Username:cdcdID:103
Username:efefID:105
```

This output is close to what I need, but still I am expecting a blank space between Username:abab ID:102.
I want to know why \1 or \2 is not working here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\([a-z]\)` - between `( )` is *one letter*. If you repeat the `\(\)` group, back reference goes to the last matched expression. Put all the repetition inside.

```
's/\([a-z]\{4\}\)\([0-9]\{3\}\)/Username:\1 ID:\2/'
```

Ugh, simpler with extended:

```
sed -E 's/([a-z]{4})([0-9]{3})/Username:\1 ID:\2/'
```

Comment: actually, it gos to the **last** not the first. Consider:: `echo abcdefg | sed 's/\([a-z]\)*/\1/'`

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/[[:alpha:]]{4}/Username:& ID:/' input_file
Username:abab ID:102
Username:cdcd ID:103
Username:efef ID:105
```

Comment: Hey @HatLess your command is incomplete.

Comment: @user5499810 What is incomplete about it? It takes the first four characters and assigns them to username. The same command also creates ID which is populated with the remaining data